# Discord bot log

Tags: javascript, logging, discord.js, bots

So, I created a discord.js bot and added the following into index.js:

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild = {
    const logsServerJoin = client.channels.get('757945781352136794');
    console.log(`The bot just joined to ${guild.name}, Owned by ${guild.owner.user.tag}`);
    client.channels.cache.get('channel id paste here').send(`The bot just joined to ${guild.name}, Owned by ${guild.owner.user.tag}`);

    var guildMSG = guild.channels.find('name', 'general');

    if (guildMSG) {
        guildMSG.send(` Hello there! My original name is \`Bryant\`!\n\ This bot created by **R 1 J 4 N#7686**\n\ For more info
       type \`/help\`!\n\ \`Bryant - Official Server:\`
       https://discord.gg/UsQFpzy`);
    } else {
        return;
    }
});

// Logs of the bot leaves a server and changed the game of the bot
client.on("guildDelete", guild = {
    client.channels.cache.get('757945781352136794').send(`The bot just
       left ${guild.name}, Owned by ${guild.owner.user.tag}`);
    console.log(`The bot has been left ${guild.name}, Owned by ${guild.owner.user.tag}`);
    logsServerLeave.send(`The bot has been left ${guild.name}, Owned by ${guild.owner.user.tag}`);
});
```

It does not show any error in the terminal. It is supposed to log me where the bot joined and left in the mentioned channel but does not ‍♂️. Can anyone help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting no console log and no message in the channel / an error telling you that the channel could not be found, the issue is most likely in how you are registering the events, make sure `client` is an instance of the discord.js Client, below is a minimal working example

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js")

const client = new Client()

client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
  console.log(`The bot just joined to ${guild.name}, Owned by ${guild.owner.user.tag}`)
})

client.login("yourtoken")
```

Comment: No dude,I actually want the log to be in my discord server's particular channel. :(

Comment: If you are getting no error it's hard to help, make sure your code runs because it should error if it does not work. In your code snippet, `logsServerLeave` is not defined anywhere for example

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the logs from your bot alert you in your home discord server you can do this multiple ways: Getting the channel from cache, Constructing the channel or Using webhooks. Currently you are trying to fetch the channel from cache. Although a decent solution it can fall down when using sharding later down the line. Personally I prefer webhooks as they are the easiest and most isolated.

#### Channel from cache

This technique is very similar to the way you were doing it.

```
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('757945781352136794')
channel.send('An Event occurred')
```

Just place this code anywhere you want to log something and you'll be fine.

#### Constructing the channel

```
const guild = new Discord.Guild(client, { id: '757945781352136794' });
const channel = new Discord.TextChannel(guild, { id: '757945781352136794' });
channel.send('An Event occurred')
```

This method is similar to fetching the channel from cache except it will be faster as you are constructing your home guild and channel and then sending to it. Mind you will need a client which you can get from `message.client`

#### Webhooks

My Favourite method uses webhooks. I recommend you read up on how discord webhooks work in both [Discord](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/228383668-Intro-to-Webhooks) and [Discord.js](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/WebhookClient)

You will also need to create a webhook. This is very easy. Go into the channel you want the webhooks to be sent to and then go to integrations and create a new webhook. You can change the name and profile as you wish but copy the url and it should look something like this:

https://discord.com/api/webhooks/757945781352136794/OkMsuUHwdStR90k7hrfEi5*********

The last part of the path is the webhook token and the bit before is the channel ID

I recommend you create a helper function that can be called like this:

```
sendWebhook('An event occurred');
```

And then write the function to create and then send to the webhook

```
function sendWebhook(text) {
    const webhook = new Discord.WebhookClient('757945781352136794', 'OkMsuUHwdStR90k7hrfEi5*********');
    webhook.send(text);
    webhook.destroy();
}
```

This will not be very dynamic and will be a pain to change the channel but for constant logging ( like guild joins and leaves ) I think it is the best solution

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that you don't have "Privileged Gateway Intents" enabled. To turn them on, go to https://discord.com/developers, click on your application, then on "Bot" then scroll down and enable "PRESENCE INTENT" and "SERVER MEMBERS INTENT" and save. It should probably work for you now.